# Long term measurement vs Short term measurements

Tags: standard-deviation, error

I have to measure the activity of a radioactive source for an assignment and the only question I can't get aroud to answering is the following:

Should I make one long term measurement (say, 120 secs) or 12 short term measurements (say, 12 measurements of 10 secs), considering that nuclear decay is poisson (std of activity = sqrt of measurement divided by measurement time).

In my understanding, both situations are completely equal. Should they differ? Why?

Comment: What are you assuming about the size of the error of your measurements? (And that's "error" as in "measurement error" in my query, not "standard error".)